# Each separate id's count in mysql in two table with join query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have two tables as like,

table_1

```
id  team_id  fav_id
1    10        1
2    10        6
3    11        5
4    12        5
5    12        1
6    25        6
```

table_2

```
league_id   team_id   name
100          10        a 
100          11        b
100          12        c
100          13        d
101          25        e
```

I need a result of all `team_id` with `league_id = 100` from `table_2` and `join` with `count` of `fav_id` for each `team_id` in `table_1` in a single query.

expecting results like,

```
league_id   team_id  name  count of(fav_id)
-------------------------------------------------
100          10       a          2
100          11       b          1
100          12       c          2
100          13       d          0
```

Any idea?

Comment: There are already hundreds of questions (with answers) here about how to join to MySQL tables together. How is your question any different from the previous ones?

Comment: How did you get different names for the same league in your example result ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    table_2.league_id,
    table_2.team_id,
    table_2.name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_1 WHERE table_1.team_id=table_2.team_id)
FROM
    table_2
WHERE
    table_2.league_id=100
```

Comment: Thanks working. great!

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does the performance of the subquery used here compare to using a join? Will the query parser generate identical query execution plans?

Comment: @Paccc I'll try to run `EXPLAIN` for this query and the one from 
John Wooes answer and compare them. I'll let you know later.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to list all `team_id` on the list having without *fav_id*, you need to join both tables using `LEFT JOIN`. The reason for using `LEFT JOIN` is because it returns all rows both table define on the *lefthand side* of the join whether it has a match on the right table or nothing at all.

```
SELECT  a.league_ID, a.team_ID, 
        COUNT(b.team_ID) totalFAV,
        a.Name
FROM    table2 a
        LEFT JOIN table1 b
            ON a.team_ID = b.team_ID
WHERE   a.league_ID = 100
GROUP   BY a.league_ID, a.team_ID, a.Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/084c0/5)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

OUTPUT

```
╔═══════════╦═════════╦══════════╦══════╗
║ LEAGUE_ID ║ TEAM_ID ║ TOTALFAV ║ NAME ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬══════════╬══════╣
║       100 ║      10 ║        2 ║ a    ║
║       100 ║      11 ║        1 ║ b    ║
║       100 ║      12 ║        2 ║ c    ║
║       100 ║      13 ║        0 ║ d    ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╩══════════╩══════╝
```

Comment: thanks for your effort

Comment: you're welcome `:D` do you need more explanation?

Comment: no thanks ! got my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.`league_id`, a.`team_id`, a.`name`, COUNT(b.id)
FROM table_2 a
LEFT JOIN table_1 b
    ON a.team_id = b.team_id
WHERE a.league_id = 100
GROUP BY a.team_id
```

I think that'd work.

Here's a fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8892/2